# how to get change global_stats for a particular partition to YES

Tags: oracle

i have sql table which has partitions.

I recently created one partition. Even if i enter data to satisfy that partition , my no of records for this partition remains null. Its not getting increased.

the only difference i found in the existing and newly creating partitions is **GLOBAL_STATS**(in table **All_tab_partitions**) is YES for all, except the one i have created now.

Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't recompute statistis automatically for every row inserted. You can analyze the partition manualy. There is also no relation to global_stats.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. How to check that my record enters into the newly created partition. Is there any method to view it.